# Remove server and system name from apache auto indexes

Tags: security, apache-2.2, indexes

I've configured apache2 to display folder content with option `Indexes` in one of my locations, but I really dislike how apache brags about its version and system's version.

How do I remove this message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be looking for the [`ServerSignature`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serversignature) option, specifically:

```
ServerSignature Off
```

Should be somewhere in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` (or wherever else your Apache main config file is).

Comment: This is it. Thanx! The option was in `conf.d/security`

Answer (score 0):

Set to Off the ServerSignature directive.